# Uncaught TypeError by using FSO.js

Tags: javascript, fso, typeerror

I'm trying to access client side files with FSO.js. At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./FSO.js-master/fso.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo(){
            var fso = new FSO(1024 * 1024 * 100, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button name="Klickmich" type="button" onclick="foo();">Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click the button, the console says "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**"

I don't really get the difference between this http://fsojs.com/ and my code except I left out the further steps.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access client sided files through `fso.js` because of security reasons, But you can use `localhost` for this work, the files which you make are temporary and erases automatically as you reboot your PC.